# Pandas - Vlookup - Duplicate values in search column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, vlookup

I am trying to mimic a v lookup (excel function) in Pandas ( using test data sets the merge function seems to work) - but I do have question regarding the example here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html . If you look at the first example it mergers the two df's, the output has more columns and more ROWS. I would just want to return a new column - like how a v lookup works. non the less , when I try my code even for the above I get this error:

```
agingdf = agingdf.merge(plannerdf, left_on ='Cust_PO_Number', right_on='Cust_PO_Number')

ValueError: The column label 'Cust_PO_Number' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.
```

Below is an open ticket that seems similar to my issues, but had no resolution.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20769

I apologize if this is vague, I can't upload the df and excel file because it is for work and the test DF's I tried did not throw the same error.

At the end of the day I just want to do a vlookup with pandas, and the vlookup values may be duplicate, so in that case just whatever duplicate value got hit first thats the value that would return in the new column.

Below, is an example df to help you imagine what I mean by duplicates in Cust_PO_Number

```
a = {'Cust_PO_Number': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'ColumnB': [1,2,3,4]}
b = {'Cust_PO_Number': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Column_That_I_Want_added': [2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=b)

desired df
c = {'ColumnA': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'ColumnB': [1,2,3,4], 'MatchedColumn', [2,3,4,5]}

desireddf = pd.DataFrame(data=c)
```

Now to explore multi- level columns

```
print(plannerdf.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Cust_PO_Number', 'Department']],
           labels=[[0, 1]])
```

Comment: What dataset size are we looking at?

Comment: So, to clarify: `plannerdf` may contain multiple rows for each unique value of `Cust_PO_Number`, and you just want to take the remaining columns that correspond to the *first* one?

Comment: 25k rows, 25 columns on the file where I have the values I am usings to vlookup, then the file I am pulling matches from is 11k rows, 20 columns or so.

Comment: So imagine a v lookup in excel , the first argument I would pass in is "Cust_PO_Number" , is this column exists in both spreadsheets. "Cust_PO_Number" - the column itself has some duplicates. That would be my only guess as to what is causing this error. Does that make sense?

Comment: @gmds see edits I made in my post. See how Cust_PO_Number has duplicate C's, that is what I mean. I am trying to pull in a new column ie Matched Column , with the matches I get. If there was a situation where the same Cust_PO_Num had a different value, that is fine , this can happen in excel and it just takes whatever it matches first.

Comment: If it can take whatever it matches first, wouldn't the result be `[2, 3, 4, 4]`, since `4` is the first value corresponding to `'C'`?

Comment: Sorry yes you are correct that was a typo

Comment: You can just use merge on `plannerdf.drop_duplicates('Cust_PO_Number')` then. That said, I do not get the error you do in that situation, which leads me to believe something else is wrong (or your version of `pandas`) might be different.

Comment: Ok , but this code will not drop the agingdf rows correct ? Because that would delete orders I need represented . I will give it a try

Comment: No, only those from `plannerdf`. However, if there are values of `Cust_PO_Number` in `plannerdf` *not* in `agingdf`, you should pass `how='left'`.

Comment: @gmds  when I tired to drop the duplicates I got this error:  KeyError: Index(['Cust_PO_Number'], dtype='object')

Comment: This confirms my suspicion that, per the error message, you actually have multi-level columns. Please include the output of `print(plannerdf.columns)` and `print(agingdf.columns)` in your question.

Comment: @gmds yes you are correct ( btw I made the df smaller, so there is only two columns the column I want to match and the column values I need to return) I'd rather note share all the column names on the agingdf, but it just says Index([...], dtype='object')

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.insert(2,'Column_That_I_Want_added', df['Cust_PO_Number'].map(df2.drop_duplicates('Cust_PO_Number').set_index('Cust_PO_Number')['Column_That_I_Want_added']))
```

where `df` is the original dataframe as well as the desired dataframe, and `df2` is where you look up the data from.

Comment: Fantastic solution. Underrated. Thank you