# vlookup behavior in pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas, vlookup

I would like to have the vlookup behavior merging two dataframes.
suppose I have the below tables in excel:

[image: excel]

using vlookup for adding "staus" column to Table2 would result like below:
[image: vlookup]

which for code "124" will return the first corresponding status "a". and that is exactly what I need.

What I try to code in python to have my desired output is like below:

```
Table1 = pd.DataFrame({"section" : ["1","2","1","2","2","2"], "code" : [124,254,156,147,124,156], "status" : ["a","b","c", "a", "b", "c"]})

Table2 = pd.DataFrame({"code": [124,254,156,147]})
```

[image: df]

```
result1 = Table1.iloc[:,1:].merge(Table2, on = 'code')
```

[image: result1]

```
result2 = Table1.iloc[:,1:].merge(Table2, on = 'code', how = 'right')
```

[image: result2]

I can manage to remove the duplicates in the results, however still I have 2 rows of the code "124" with status "a" and "b".

I have also searched through the posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582808/pandas-vlookup-duplicate-values-in-search-column) but that wouldn't be help.
any recommendation regarding the solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Just drop the duplicates with `Table2.merge(Table1, on="code").drop_duplicates("code")`?

Comment: you need to drop the dupes in your first table befor you merge.

Comment: @Datanovice but the code "124" in table1 is not duplicate. the first row has section 1 and status a and the second record has section 2 and status b.

Comment: yup and your doing a right join so its returning every key in the right table with its matching key in the left table, that's expected behavior?

Comment: @Datanovice but I want to have only the first match.

Answer (score 0):

```py
Table1 = pd.DataFrame({"section" : ["1","2","1","2","2","2"], "code" : [124,254,156,147,124,156], "status" : ["a","b","c", "a", "b", "c"]})
df1=Table1.drop_duplicates("code") #create new df without duplicates code
Table2 = pd.DataFrame({"code": [124,254,156,147]})

result2 = df1.iloc[:,1:].merge(Table2, on = 'code', how = 'right')
```

Comment: Tested n give result as per request.